# Automatic or Unattended updates

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to get crontab to automatically schedule an update via "sudo apt-get update". I have also written a script that if I run it through Terminal (/home/pi/bin/update), it runs the update script but if I schedule crontab to run the update script, nothing. I also added the command "0 05 * * * sudo apt-get update" (run update at 05:00 every morning) into crontab and nothing either. If the update is running I don't see the update running in Terminal or even know if the command has run. What could I be missing?

Comment: Do you need to enter a password for user `pi` when running `sudo`? Why not run `apt-get update` directly as root?

Comment: You will not see any terminal output when cron runs a job. The script is running in its cron's shell, not yours. Redirecting the output to a file like CoderMike suggests below will enable you to see what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Check the log file to see if your cron command was executed:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Direct the output to a file to see the result of the command:

(test every minute)

```
*/1 * * * * sudo apt-get update > /home/pi/log.txt
```

(05:00 every day)

```
0 5 * * * sudo apt-get update > /home/pi/log.txt
```